# run program at startup without entering administrator password

Tags: boot, cmd.exe

I am trying to run programs, which require administator's password on an account without administrator rights: without entering a password every time they are launched at startup!


**Source:**

https://www.howtogeek.com/124087/how-to-create-a-shortcut-that-lets-a-standard-user-run-an-application-as-administrator/


I tried creating a shortcut and using this command:

```
runas /user:Laptop\Administrator /savecred "C:\Program Files\CCleaner\CCleaner.exe"
```

Unfortunately without success!

Please help.

Comment: Look over this answer and just triple confirm nothing is being overlooked in this setup with the shortcut just in case it can't hurt. . . https://serverfault.com/questions/734320/allow-standard-user-to-run-program-as-local-admin-without-elevation-prompt/734360#734360 ... Try with the username of `.\administrator` as well and see if that makes any difference if you see nothing else per that post.

Comment: If these programs are to be run on start-up, you should be able to configure Task Scheduler to handle this. Run in `SYSTEM` or Administrator account. Look through the Microsoft->Windows tasks for something similar to use as a template.

Comment: With .\administrator added after username it says new notice:"RUNAS ERROR: unable to acquire user password." I used command %systemroot%\system32\runas.exe /user:username.\administrator\ProxyRunAsLocalAdmin /savecred "C:\Program Files\CCleaner\CCleaner.exe" also i noticed, that they have in "start in" field under shotcut path to the program istead C:\Windows\System32 and changed it and it had no effect

Comment: Be sure you have this value in the "**Target**" field instead: `%systemroot%\system32\runas.exe /user:.\administrator /savecred "C:\Program Files\CCleaner\CCleaner.exe"`. Be sure you have this value in the **Start in** field: `C:\Program Files\CCleaner` and then try again. Be sure you know the administrator account is enabled and activated and that you know for sure the password is correct that you type in for it to save with the `/savecred` switch on the first run of the command using it per each profile that runs the shortcut with the saved credential.

Comment: Actually domain\user made it work. But i have another problem, program is not launching and cmd close instantly to fast even for moving per frames to see. And i don't know how to keep open cmd, when launched from shotcut after execution.

Comment: See https://www.ccleaner.com/docs/ccleaner/advanced-usage/command-line-parameters and consider just setting up a job on Task Scheduler and run with the `/AUTO` switch maybe. I've never used ccleaner in the runas fashion like you are attempting here but if you're trying to keep PC profiles clean, see if you can automate from Task Scheduler and just run at specific times every day if that'd suffice for your need.